# validating radiogroup with perl/cgi

Tags: perl, cgi

Is it possible to validate a radio group (so something is checked off, or chosen) using server-side validation with Perl? If so, how?

I already have it for JavaScript, but I want this form to be able to be submitted even without JavaScript enabled. Thus I will need the validation on the server-side.

There is no fixed name for the radio group, it can change, however there must be a name, so that `@names = $cgi->param()` will give all the names.

I'm thinking along something that will give me the type, like the type in JavaScript, to determine if it's a radio button in a group.

Comment: Please stop using the dirty old CGI.pm. Use instead a modern and clean web engine such as [Dancer](http://www.perldancer.org/) or [Mojolicious](http://mojolicious.org/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your CGI script receives form fields as name-value pairs without any information as to what type of visual form element generated the values.

Your CGI script must know the names of the input variables whose values it is going to validate. Having the names supplied to the script based on untrusted user input is risky IMHO—that includes using another field whose value is the name of the radio group.

Say, you have a variable called `contact_me` which can take on values `"yes"` and `"no"`. There is absolutely no reason for your CGI script to care if the value was provided using

```
<select name="contact_me">
<option value="yes" selected="1">Please do!</option>
<option value="no">Oh no!!!</option>
</select>
```

or using

```
<input type="radio" name="contact_me" value="yes" checked="1">
<input type="radio" name="contact_me" value="no">
```

or if the user typed her answer into the text field

```
<input name="contact_me">
```

The only thing your CGI script needs to concern itself with is if the value of `contact_me` is `"yes"` or `"no"`.

It looks like you do not have a firm grasp of CGI. Please see [The World Wide Web Security FAQ: CGI (Server) Scripts](http://www.w3.org/Security/Faq/wwwsf4.html) as a starting point.

<s>Please stop **all** of your CGI development until you understand the ramifications.</s> I retract this remark in light of your comments clarifying the use of a config file to define parameter names (which, in principle, is orders of magnitude safer).

Comment: Okay thank you! So it is not possible to see types.

Would an alternative be to have a default radio with the same name to something that would trigger a failure, when I use the config file as a basis and make it default to a generic?
 
Or do the hidden field way?

Comment: @Tyug: First, there are no types. You are confusing a user interface element with a type. Second, I have no idea what you mean with the sentence *Would an alternative be to have a default radio with the same name to something that would trigger a failure, when I use the config file as a basis and make it default to a generic?* Finally, don't trust information submitted to your CGI script to determine how the CGI script should validate inputs. **Maybe you should explain why you cannot use a known name for the radio group.**

Comment: Oh.. my bad for not being clear. I understand that there are no types.<br/>
The second part is my thought of an alternative, which is to append another radio if there are none that is defaulted to. Thus guaranteeing that there will be a value in the radio group. 
The reason why I cannot know the name of the radio group is because they change depending on the config file chosen. Sometimes they might not even be there, and sometimes there may be more because due to the dynamic form. I also do not know which config they will use.

Comment: @Tyug I think it is time for you to formulate a coherent question collecting all these tidbits into something that fits together. What config file? Who are **they**? Think about these and write up a new question. You seem to have an X-Y problem: http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#explicit

Comment: Nope, I understood where I went wrong, and a better, more safe, way of avoiding the problem. Thanks to your security link. It was a helpful read.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your input!

Comment: Yep, my new design is much better and safer! Thanks a lot, seriously. I remembered why I had the config files, and it was for validation reasons and not just to render the form. Saved me a lot of pain from potential attacks. I'm glad this is my first CGI form.

Comment: @Tyug Your problem setup and solution makes a lot of sense now. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Pass another hidden input field containing the name of the radiogroup, then just read

```
@values = $cgi->param($cgi->param("radiogroup_name")); // IIRC
```

Comment: And if the client suppresses this input field when posting to the server?

Comment: Oesor, how would the client suppress a hidden field?

Comment: @Tyug Whether a field is hidden is a user interface choice. I am afraid you do not know enough to know what you don't know when it comes to CGI programming. What happens in your script when someone types `http://example.com/shoot-myself-in-the-foot.pl?radiovar=yabadabadooo`?

Comment: Furthermore, I have protection against double submissions.

Comment: @Tyug I guess you have not heard of `wget` or `curl` or even Web Developer plugin for Firefox? You know what: Feel free to do whatever you want. But I have to point out that there is no good reason the server side script should not know the names of the inputs.

Comment: @Tyug => POST doesn't protect you, its just marginally harder to spoof

Comment: I have realized that... My mistake for going after what I thought would be a "simple" solution. After having a very problematic day yesterday. I guess this is what happens when someone gives me a project without real specifications.